# Rails 5: Displaying object value not ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple app for a skydiving dropzone. Parachute packers keep track of their packsjobs. There are several packjobs for each parachute rig.

I have the Show view working perfectly by showing the rig_type_number under the rig detail (ie Reflex #2) but I can only get the rig_id to work in the same column for the index. Ideally, I'd like to so the rig_type_number as well instead of the ID.

How can I reference in the view something to the effect of **@rigs.rig_type_number?**

This makes sense to me, but does not work:

```
<td><%= link_to packjob.rig_id,rig_path(rig.rig_type_number) %>
```

Will I have to a where clause for the index controller?

[image]

[image]

db:

```
class CreatePackjobs < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :packjobs do |t|
      t.string :packer
      t.string :rig
      t.references :rig, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end

  end
end

class CreateRigs < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :rigs do |t|
      t.boolean :rig_status
      t.string :rig_type_number
      t.integer :rig_season_jumpnum
      t.date :rig_res_last
      t.string :rig_res_who

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

packjobs_controller:

```
class PackjobsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @packjobs = Packjob.paginate(page: params[:page]).order('id DESC') 
    @rigs = Rig.where(rig_status: "t")
  end

  def show
    @packjob = Packjob.find(params[:id])
    @rig = Rig.find(@packjob.rig_id)
  end

  def new
    @packjob = Packjob.new
    @rigs = Rig.where(rig_status: "t")
  end

  def edit
    @packjob = Packjob.find(params[:id])
    @rigs = Rig.where(rig_status: "t")
  end

  def create
    @packjob = Packjob.new(packjob_params)
    @rigs = Rig.where(rig_status: "t")
    if @packjob.save
      redirect_to @packjob
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end


  def update
    @packjob = Packjob.find(params[:id])
    @rigs = Rig.where(rig_status: "t")
    if @packjob.update(packjob_params)
      redirect_to @packjob
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end


  def destroy
    @packjob = Packjob.find(params[:id])
    @packjob.destroy

    redirect_to packjobs_path
  end

  private
    def packjob_params
      params.require(:packjob).permit(:packer, :rig_id)
    end

    def rigs_params
      params.require(:rig).permit(:rig_status, :rig_type_number)
    end


end
```

show.html.erb:

```
<p>
   <b>Datestamp:</b>
   <%= @packjob.created_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %P") %><br>
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Packer:</strong>
  <%= @packjob.packer %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Rig:</strong>
  <%= @rig.rig_type_number %><br>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_packjob_path(@packjob) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', packjobs_path %>
```

index.html.erb:

```
<h1>Listing Packjobs</h1>

<%= link_to 'New Packjob', new_packjob_path %> | <br>

<br>

<div class="digg_pagination">
  <%= will_paginate @packjobs, :container => false %>
</div>

<table id=listtable CELLPADDING="4" border="1">
  <tr class="headerBlue" >
    <th>Datestamp</th>
    <th>Packer</th>
    <th>Rig</th>
    <th colspan="3"></th>
  </tr>

  <% @packjobs.each do |packjob| %>
  <tr class="<%= cycle('rowA', 'rowB') %>">
        <td><%= link_to packjob.created_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %P"),packjob_path(packjob.id) %></td>
        <td><%= packjob.packer %></td>
        <td><%= link_to packjob.rig_id,rig_path(packjob.rig_id) %>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', packjob_path(packjob) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_packjob_path(packjob) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', packjob_path(packjob),
          method: :delete,
          data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>

    <% end %>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="digg_pagination">
  <div class="page_info">
    <%= page_entries_info @packjobs %>
  </div>
  <%= will_paginate @packjobs,  :container => false %>
</div>

<br><%= link_to 'New Packjob', new_packjob_path %> |
```

**EDITED:**

models:

```
class Packjob < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :rig
  validates :packer, presence: true
  validates :rig_id, presence: true

  self.per_page = 25
end

class Rig < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :packjobs
  validates :rig_type_number, presence: true
  self.per_page = 25

end
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear - can you break down precisely what you would like to do vs. what is currently happening?

Comment: sorry :S... I would like to display on the index the name of the rig ie "Reflex #2" and not just the rig record id, "7".

Comment: Can you post your Packjob and Rig models as well?

Comment: @AnthonyL: models added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your associations are set correctly, you can reference the associated object like this:

```
<td><%= link_to packjob.rig.rig_type_number,rig_path(packjob.rig_id) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call it as below in case you have `has_one :rig` association in **PackJob** model :

```
<td><%= link_to packjob..rig.rig_type_number,rig_path(packjob.rig_id) if packjob.rig.present? %> </td>
```

Comment: Is there a difference between belongs_to :rig and has_one :rig?

Comment: A good article to know the difference http://requiremind.com/differences-between-has-one-and-belongs-to-in-ruby-on-rails/